# What is the most effective way in .NET 4.0 to require input parameter collection to be sorted using Code Contracts?

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, static-analysis, code-contracts

How to implement input parameter sorted precondition enforcement?

Comment: Why was this closed? The question is not ambiguous, nor overly broad. There are sensible answers for this.

Comment: @porges I agree. It's a perfectly clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of code would help us all with helping you.

I'll assume you have a method along the lines of this..

```
public void MyMethod(params string[] list) {...}
```

and you want to use Code Contracts to ensure that this method will only ever be called with a sorted list. Did you try something like the following for the body?

```
Contract.Requires(list.OrderBy(s => s).SequenceEquals(list));
```

Comment: Might be better to use an [IsSorted()](https://github.com/colgreen/Redzen/blob/master/Redzen/Sorting/SortUtils.cs) method unless the sort being used by Linq guarantees that items won't be moved if already sorted (which it might do even if it's not a stable sort algorithm more generally). It's also likely that an IsSorted() method would be more efficient.

Comment: @redcalx Sure, if you're ok with adding another dependency to your project or writing your own optimized implementation for such a thing, you can surely optimize. Though, the question asks for effective, not efficient, so we should keep Donald Knuth in mind. ;)

Comment: Performance aside, the other point about correctness stands; i.e. the sequences may both be sorted but not equal.

Comment: @redcalx If you're worried that .OrderBy(..) will modify the list, that won't happen. Each step produced by linq will create a new enumerable. I'm sufficiently sure the assurances of this exist that I won't bother looking them up. Maybe some fringe linq driver will do that, but then it will surely be violating the spec.